# BIRT add existing aggregation through UI

Tags: birt

I want to add an existing aggregation to a report. For simple parameters from a dataset it's easy, just drag drop.

I've been deleting and recreating them in the past and i'm tired of doing that. I could do it through the XML, but it'd be easy to just drag-drop through the UI if there's a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to deleting and recreating them, "BIRT: A Field Guide" by Peh, Hague and Tatchell suggests the following:

1. Insert a *text* element where you want to display the aggregation value.
2. In the Edit Text Item dialog, select HTML from the dropdown list that initially displays Auto.
3. Enter a formula like the following: `<VALUE-OF>row["`*aggregation-name*`"]</VALUE-OF>`
   (*aggregation-name* should be replaced with the name of the aggregation binding from the table.)
4. Press OK to save the specified expression for the text element.

For relatively simple aggregations, I find it easier to delete and recreate them.

Comment: while this will work for the simple stuff, formatting this value as a currency seems to be a bit more cumbersome than the formatting tools provided by the aggregation element in the properties window. Seems that all my summaries use aggregation formatting in some way or another. Thanks though!